# How to Set the Values dynamically to preperaedStatement in this case

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using a Java Prepared Statement to build a dynamic SQL this way. Could you please let me know how I can set the values dynamically?

This is my code:

I am getting the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
```

This is my code

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4616)
    at Test.main(Test.java:72)

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.text.ParseException;

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        try
        {

        String sqlUpdateforemp = "update emp_details set emp_name=? , emp_author = ? , emp_description = ?";


        String str_Preview_Pic = "";
        String str_Thumb_Nail_Pic = "";
        String str_How_to_Video = "";
        String str_emp_id = "1";
        PreparedStatement Stmtupdateforemp = null;
        Connection dbConnectionFitSh = null;

         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         String sURL="jdbc:mysql:/fdsfds/fdsfse_qa";
            String sUserName="root";
            String sPwd="fdsf";
         dbConnectionFitSh = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL,sUserName,sPwd);

        StringBuffer stringbuffer_sql = new StringBuffer(sqlUpdateforemp);
        int paramInd = 0;

        if (str_Preview_Pic != null && !str_Preview_Pic.isEmpty()) {
            stringbuffer_sql.append(",emp_preview_pic=?");
        }


        if (str_Thumb_Nail_Pic != null && !str_Thumb_Nail_Pic.isEmpty()) {
            stringbuffer_sql.append(",emp_thumbnail=?");
        }


        if (str_How_to_Video != null && !str_How_to_Video.isEmpty()) {
            stringbuffer_sql.append(",emp_video=?");
        }


        stringbuffer_sql.append("where emp_id='" + str_emp_id + "'");
        Stmtupdateforemp = dbConnectionFitSh.prepareStatement(stringbuffer_sql.toString());

        Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  "emp_name");
        Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  "emp_author");
        Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  "emp_description");

         if (str_Preview_Pic != null && !str_Preview_Pic.isEmpty()) {
             Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd, str_Preview_Pic);
            }

            if (str_Thumb_Nail_Pic != null && !str_Thumb_Nail_Pic.isEmpty()) {
                Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd, str_Thumb_Nail_Pic);
            }

            if (str_How_to_Video != null && !str_How_to_Video.isEmpty()) {
                Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd, str_How_to_Video);
            }
            Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  str_emp_id);

            System.out.println(Stmtupdateforemp);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String sqlUpdateforemp = "update emp_details set emp_name=? , emp_author = ? , emp_description = ? ,emp_description= ? ,  emp_thumbnail_name = ? ,emp_subscription=?";

    StringBuffer stringbuffer_sql = new StringBuffer(sqlUpdateforemp);
    int paramInd = 0;
    if (str_Preview_Pic != null && !str_Preview_Pic.isEmpty()) {
        stringbuffer_sql.append(",emp_preview_pic=?");
    }

    if (str_Thumb_Nail_Pic != null && !str_Thumb_Nail_Pic.isEmpty()) {
        stringbuffer_sql.append(",emp_thumbnail=?");
    }

    if (str_How_to_Video != null && !str_How_to_Video.isEmpty()) {
        stringbuffer_sql.append(",emp_video=?");
    }

    stringbuffer_sql.append("where emp_id=?");
    PreparedStatement Stmtupdateforemp = dbConnection.prepareStatement(stringbuffer_sql.toString());
    Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  % emp_name_VARIABLE %);
    Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  % emp_author_VARIABLE %);
    Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  % emp_description_VARIABLE %);
    Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  % emp_description_VARIABLE %);
    Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  % emp_thumbnail_name_VARIABLE %);
    Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  % emp_subscription_VARIABLE %);
    if (str_Preview_Pic != null && !str_Preview_Pic.isEmpty()) {
        Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd, str_Preview_Pic);
    }

    if (str_Thumb_Nail_Pic != null && !str_Thumb_Nail_Pic.isEmpty()) {
        Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd, str_Thumb_Nail_Pic);
    }

    if (str_How_to_Video != null && !str_How_to_Video.isEmpty()) {
        Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd, str_How_to_Video);
    }
    Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  % YOUR_EMPID_VARIABLE %);
```

Comment: what will be the initial vaue of paramInd  ??

Comment: 0(zero), It will pre increment before you set parameter to preparestatement

Comment: How wil this work , as emp_description  will be three know ?

Comment: Thnanks , but  i am getting a exception , updated my code in my question , please tell me whats thw wrong ?

Comment: Remove this line
 Stmtupdateforemp.setString(++paramInd,  str_emp_id);
You already appended  str_emp_id in the query string

Comment: Please explain your solution in words, so people can actually understand how you address the question instead of having to meticulously study the code for differences.